# Use html session storage to hide a div after it's run once

Tags: javascript, syntax, sessionstorage

I have this div with an id of se-pre-con in my website which I only want to display once per website visit. I want to use session storage to display none the html div of se-pre-con  after it's run once. But could do with some advice about how to approach this.

```
 <div class="se-pre-con"></div> // the relevant html

.no-js #loader { display: none;  } // the relevant css
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url(Preloader_10.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}

 <script> // the relevant jquery

// Wait for window load
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});


</script>
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comments, but I still believe the gist of my answer is still helpful to your case (except the parts where I suggest you call `fadeObject`. Would you agree or do you think that has nothing to do with what you're asking? If you think it doesn't help I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Your answer is somewhere along the lines of what's needed. I can't mark it correct as yet though. Rolling the two functions into one is the correct approach like you say, I have another entirely javascript function that does exactly that and works, but I think it's syntax bugs to do with mixing javascript and jquery as to why mines not right so far.

Comment: jQuery is a library, it can't cause syntax errors by mixing it with JavaScript, but you may be using incompatible objects. If you could post a relevant part of your script that is causing an error and specify *what* the error is and *how* it is manifesting itself it would be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Sure, fadeout slow is attached to the load event, because I don't want the loading gif to fadeout until the image gallery and it's four pictures are fully loaded in the browsers memory. Here's my early attempt at the script. The error is at the moment the loading gif is not fading out.<script>


$(window).load(function() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('se-pre-con') !== 'false') {
     $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow"); 
    } 
}
else {
        document.getElementById('se-pre-con').style.display="none";
        sessionStorage.setItem('se-pre-con','true');
       
    }

</script>

Comment: There's something wrong with the code you posted in the comment (an `else` without a corresponding `if`). Also, please update your answer, as code in comments is hard to read. Still, if I understand what you actually wanted to do, the code in my answer seems to actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question by using this script in the body section of the html page, it ensures the loader only ever runs once per browser session, exactly as I was trying to achieve.

```
<script>
if (sessionStorage.getItem('se-pre-con') !== 'true'){
// if the storage item 'se-pre-con', does not exist, run the code in curly 
braces
document.getElementById("se-pre-con").style.display = 'block';}

else {
document.getElementById('se-pre-con').style.display="none";
// else (when above if statement is not met) hide the loader
}


sessionStorage.setItem('se-pre-con','true');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still not clear where you want to call that code from, but if I were you, I would reverse the code a bit. That is, always execute your stuff on the `load` event and decide what to do while in there. At that point it becomes trivial to put the loading of the object you want to fade out inside a function and call that piece of code from somewhere else (and you don't specify where you want to call it from, so I'll have to guess you want to call it after you set the value inside your `sessionStorage`.

```
function fadeObject() {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
}

$(window).load(function() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('htmldivwithid') !== 'false') {
        fadeObject();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('htmldivwithid').style.display="none";
        sessionStorage.setItem('htmldivwithid','true');
        // call fadeObject()?
    }
});
```

At this point you can call `fadeObject()` when you need it, from inside the `load` event (I put a comment where I expect you might want to call it).

`fadeObject` is not strictly necessary, but in case you need to change the object that fades you now have just one place to change instead of two, once you decide where you want to call it.