# not able to set Conditions if a cookie exists

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

i've made a closable banner with Html, CSS and JS . 
Everything works fine but i want to make it disappear once the user hit the Close Button and never be shown again ( while changing from Site to another or after refreshing the browser ) 
i've stored a cookie , but my code to do changes if the cookie exists doesn't work

what i'm doing wrong?

```js
 



  var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
            var i;
            
            for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
                close[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
                });
            }

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
        function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
        


function checkCookie() {
  var x=getCookie("clicklink");
  if (x == null) {
   document.getElementById("close").style.display='block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("close").style.display='none';
    
  }
}
```

```css
.closable{
            margin-top: -1px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
.close{
            
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 15%;
            right: 0%;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            transform: translate(0%, -50%);
            
        }
        
.close:hover{
            background: #bbb;
       }
```

```html
   

 <div id="close" class="closable" onload="checkCookie()">
   <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong></p>
   <p style="text-align: center">
      s simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
   </p>
    <span class="close" id="clink" onclick="setCookie('clicklink', 'yes', 7)">
        &times;
    </span>
    
</div>
```

Comment: you need to store a cookie, or local storage data and only show once you have checked this first.  (ref:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) and then if you are showing it (i.e. no storage data, or cookie was found), set storage or cookie to show it was shown previousl, when the user clicks your close button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48629851/3238940

Comment: @developer i've updated my code , but still cannot set Conditions if my cookie exists , am i missing something ?